# Check multiple variables excluding same ones?

Tags: python

So I have a code that compares variables, for example A = 01, B = 101, I = 1011. I have to check if for example B starts with the same code as I. B = 101, I = **101**1. Problem arises when two same variables are being compared, for example A = 01 and A = **01**. I don't need to compare variables that have the same name. What do I do in this situation?

```
A, B, I, L, O, S, C = '01', '101', '1011', '01', '1110', '1111', '0001'

def error_fano():
    flag = 0
    for a in ['A', 'B', 'I', 'L', 'O', 'S', 'C']:
        for b in ['A', 'B', 'I', 'L', 'O', 'S', 'C']:
            if a.startswith(b) or b.startswith(a):
                flag = 1
    return flag

if error_fano() == 0:
    ABSCISSA = f'{A} {B} {S} {C} {I} {S} {S} {A}'
    length = len(ABSCISSA) - 7
    print(length, ABSCISSA)
```

I need so all letters follow the fano rule, so B doesn't start with A. But if A = A it is okay

Comment: you can add a `if a == b: continue` inside your loops

Comment: Can you edit your description please. The last comparison is "A = 01 and A = 01". 

Not sure what your asking for as a result.

Comment: Your `error_fano()` function  is *always* returning `None` — so the `if error_fano() == 0:` will never allow the statements following it to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to avoid the diagonal of a matrix. You can use enumerate and check when index i and j are equal:

```
A, B, I, L, O, S, C = '01', '101', '1011', '01', '1110', '1111', '0001'                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                              
def error_fano():                                                                                                                                                                             
    flag = 0                                                                                                                                                                                  
    for i,a in enumerate(['A', 'B', 'I', 'L', 'O', 'S', 'C']):                                                                                                                                
        for j,b in enumerate(['A', 'B', 'I', 'L', 'O', 'S', 'C']):                                                                                                                            
            if j!=i:                                                                                                                                                                          
                if a.startswith(b) or b.startswith(a):                                                                                                                                        
                    flag = 1                                                                                                                                                                  
            else:                                                                                                                                                                             
                print('do nothing when i,j are equal: ' + str(i) +","+str(j))                                                                                                                 
    return flag                                                                                                                                                                               
print('hello')                                                                                                                                                                                
if error_fano() == 0:                                                                                                                                                                         
    ABSCISSA = f'{A} {B} {S} {C} {I} {S} {S} {A}'                                                                                                                                             
    length = len(ABSCISSA) - 7                                                                                                                                                                
    print(length, ABSCISSA)
```

output:

```
hello
do nothing when i,j are equal: 0,0
do nothing when i,j are equal: 1,1
do nothing when i,j are equal: 2,2
do nothing when i,j are equal: 3,3
do nothing when i,j are equal: 4,4
do nothing when i,j are equal: 5,5
do nothing when i,j are equal: 6,6
27 01 101 1111 0001 1011 1111 1111 01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def error_fano():
    flag = 0
    for a in ['01', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '016']:
         for b in ['01', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '016']:
             if  a!=b:
                 if a.startswith(b) or b.startswith(a):
                     flag=1
                     print(a,b)

error_fano()
```

I am not clear with your statement so i assume this two list
output
01 016
016 01

Comment: The problem is that I'm ok if a[0] == b[0], but not ok if a[0] == b[1]

Comment: try to use zip , like   for a, b in zip(list1,list2)

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I'm still not 100% sure of what your asking, so this may be wrong.

```
A, B, I, L, O, S, C = '01', '101', '1011', '01', '1110', '1111', '0001'

def error_fano():
    flag = 0

    i1 = 0
    for a in [A, B, I, L, O, S, C]:
        i2 = 0
        for b in [A, B, I, L, O, S, C]:
            if (a.startswith(b) or b.startswith(a)) and i1 != i2:
                flag = 1
            i2 +=1
        
        i1 +=1
            
    return flag
```

The i1 & i2 counters keep track of what entry within the list [A, B... , C] your addressing, so prevent a comparison of i to i.

Comment: If one letter starts with the code of other letter or the code is the same. But I do not need to check if letters are the same, so this might be helpful I guess

Comment: I must be misreading - I assume it its not as simple as: "if (a.startswith(b) or b.startswith(a)) and and a != b:"

??